# Setting chrome capabilities in application.properties file using QAF Automation framework is not working

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, qaf

I'm new to using QAF Automation framework. I followed the documentation on this page - https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/setting_driver_capabilities.html

My requirement is: I have to download a file in my test and the download should go to my project's download folder and not on macbook/test machine's download folder.

I'm using chromeDriver and have to set chrome capabilities in the application.properties file within QAF framework. I added the below but it's not working

```
chrome.capabilities.profile.default_content_settings.popups=0
chrome.capabilities.download.default_directory=/downloads
chrome.capabilities.credentials_enable_service=false
chrome.capabilities.profile.password_manager_enabled=false
chrome.capabilities.CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS=true
chrome.additional.capabilities={"chrome options":{"args":["--headless -
-disable-gpu"]}}
```

I also tried directly using chrome.additional.capabilities for all the capabilities I wanted to set, like below, and it didn't work either

```
 chrome.additional.capabilities={"chrome options":{"args":["--allow-
 outdated-plugins","--always-authorize-plugins","--headless --disable-
 gpu","-disable-extensions"]},"prefs":
 [{"profile.default_content_settings.popups":0},
 {"download.default_directory":"/downloads"},
 {"credentials_enable_service":false},
 {"profile.password_manager_enabled":false}]}
```

When I execute my test, the test runs successfully and passes but the file is downloaded to my macbook download directory and not within my project specific download folder I've set using capabilities.

I tried using chromeDriver.capabilities instead of chrome.capabilities with no success.

Can anyone who used QAF before, help me with solving this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Few correction needs in additional capability value:

- Key for chrome options is `chromeOptions`
- preferences is also one of the option which requires map with key `prefs`
- Try providing absolute path for download directory.

Your additional capability should look like below (make sure there is no line break):

```
 chrome.additional.capabilities={"chromeOptions":{"args":["--allow-
 outdated-plugins","--always-authorize-plugins","--headless --disable-
 gpu","-disable-extensions"],"prefs":
 {"profile.default_content_settings.popups":0,
 "download.default_directory":"/usr/workspace/testproject/downloads",
 "credentials_enable_service":false,
 "profile.password_manager_enabled":false}}}
```

Refer [chromeOptions-object](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities#TOC-chromeOptions-object)

**EDIT:**
depending on driver version, you may required to add `goog` prefix in chrome specific capabilites, for example:

```
chrome.additional.capabilities={"goog:chromeOptions":{"args":["start-maximized","--ignore-certificate-errors"]}}
```

Below example shows how you can append capability with complex object before driver initialization using listener. For instance, in order to use **Firefox profile** you can utilize [qaf driver listener](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/qaf_listeners.html).

```
@Override
public void beforeInitialize(Capabilities desiredCapabilities) {
    FirefoxProfile profile= new FirefoxProfile();
    //create and set profile as per need
    profile.setPreference( "layout.css.devPixelsPerPx", "0.9" ); 
    ((DesiredCapabilities)desiredCapabilities).setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);

   //you also can provide existing profile name. AFAIK firefoxdriver supports existing profile name as well.
   //((DesiredCapabilities)desiredCapabilities).setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, "my-profile"); 
}
```

```
@Override
    public void beforeInitialize(Capabilities desiredCapabilities) {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        //set options and merge to capabilites
        //options.addExtensions(paths);
        desiredCapabilities.merge(options);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Below settings are placed in application.properties file.

For Chrome:

```
driver.name=chromeDriver
chrome.capabilities={"chromeOptions":{"args":["--allow-outdated-plugins","--always-authorize-plugins","--headless --disable-gpu","-disable-extensions"],"prefs":{"profile.default_content_settings.popups":0,"download.default_directory":"C:\\server","credentials_enable_service":false,"profile.password_manager_enabled":false}}}
webdriver.chrome.driver =C:/server/chromedriver.exe
```

Below setting worked for me for IE11

```
driver.name=iExplorerdriver
system.webdriver.ie.driver = C:/server/IEDriverServer.exe
iexplorer.additional.capabilities={'ignoreProtectedModeSettings':true}
iexplorer.additional.capabilities={'nativeEvents':false}
iexplorer.additional.capabilities={'unexpectedAlertBehaviour':accept}
iexplorer.additional.capabilities={'enablePersistentHover':true}
iexplorer.additional.capabilities={'ignoreZoomSetting':true}
iexplorer.additional.capabilities={'requireWindowFocus':true}
iexplorer.additional.capabilities={"ignoreProtectedModeSettings":"true",'nativeEvents':false,'unexpectedAlertBehaviour':accept,'enablePersistentHover':true,'ignoreZoomSetting':true,'requireWindowFocus':true}
iexplorer.additional.capabilities={'ignoreProtectedModeSettings':true,'nativeEvents':false,'unexpectedAlertBehaviour':accept,'enablePersistentHover':true,'ignoreZoomSetting':true,'requireWindowFocus':true}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @user861594 for answering the question.

I recently found out an easier way to set this chrome capabilities in the BaseTestCase class itself and not in application.properties.

Here is what I did and it worked wonderfully!!

Declare your filePath = "xyz";

```
String chromePrefs = "{'acceptSslCerts': true,'chromeOptions':   {'prefs': {'prompt_for_download': false,'download.default_directory': '"+filePath+"'}}}";
      ConfigurationManager.getBundle().setProperty("chrome.additional.capabilities", chromePrefs);
```

Enjoy automating!

Comment: To provide capabilities through code, you also can use driver listener https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/qaf_listeners.html#webdriver-listener you can append capabilities in ```void beforeInitialize(Capabilities)``` method

Comment: @user861594, How do i set Firefox profile setting in qaf. lets say i have to add `FirefoxProfile profile= new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference( "layout.css.devPixelsPerPx", "0.9" );
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);` profile setting

Comment: Here is the example using driver listener:


       @Override
 public void beforeInitialize(Capabilities desiredCapabilities) {
  FirefoxProfile profile= new FirefoxProfile(); 
  profile.setPreference( "layout.css.devPixelsPerPx", "0.9" ); 
    ((DesiredCapabilities)desiredCapabilities).setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
 }

I am updating original answer refer it for better formatted answer.