# Is there any option to handle certificate errors for chrome browser?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, qaf

I am developing my new Automation project, is any any option to handle certificate errors  for chrome browser? like we have for selenium -

ChromeOptions opt= new ChromeOptions();

opt.addArguments("ignore-certificate-errors");

Comment: Does that help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24507078/how-to-deal-with-certificates-using-selenium

Answer (score 1):

When using qaf you can set driver capabilities using properties. You can find details in documentation for [setting driver capabilities](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/setting_driver_capabilities.html). When setting capabilities through property, you can provide json representation of capabilities  Object. If you don't know how to create json, easiest way is to create capability object and print using `JSONUtil.toString(capability)` in console, then use it. Below is an example to set to set chrome options:

```
chrome.additional.capabilities={"chromeOptions":{"args":["--ignore-certificate-errors"]}}
```

Another way to provide capabilities through code, you can use [driver listener](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/qaf_listeners.html#webdriver-listener) you can append capabilities in `void beforeInitialize(Capabilities)` method

You can also refer [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45313983/setting-chrome-capabilities-in-application-properties-file-using-qaf-automation/45341056).