# Can we change binary path location in QAF framework

Tags: selenium, github, selenium-chromedriver, cucumber, qaf

I have a requirement to run application in chrome beta version using **Qmetry Automation framework**.
I tried to change binary path using capabilities and other different ways but none of them worked, Could please help in providing solution

Comment: Will you share what capabilities you have used along with version of selenium and qaf?

Comment: Below is the capability settings{“chromeOptions”:{“binary”:”Beta Driver path”}}

Answer (score 0):

Looks like issue is in capability value. Try adding `goog:` prefix to key `chromeOptions`, for example:

```
chrome.additional.capabilities={"goog:chromeOptions":{"binary":"Path to the Chrome executable"}}
```

Here is easiest way to generate or validate Capabilities:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setBinary("Path to the Chrome executable");
    
    System.out.println(JSONUtil.toString(options.toJson()));
}
```

Refer [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45341056/861594) of similar question for another way to set capability through code using [driver listener](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/qaf_listeners.html).